# Making input go to the bottom of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know why on the code snippet here, it fits in the div perfectly, but on my hosting site, and on phpfiddle.org, the outer div is twice the height of the contents on the inside, so I tried to use bottom: 0; on the input to make to make the contents go to the bottom of the outer div, but it didn't work. What should I do instead?

```css
#login {
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
}
input {
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'login'>
<form method = 'POST' action = 'login.php'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'username' maxlength = '20' placeholder = 'username' size = '5'>
<input type = 'password' name = 'password' maxlength = '20' placeholder = 'password' size = '5'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Login'>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to your live site, since seeing a perfectly fine form won't help much in understanding the problem on your side.

Comment: Sure. http://randomcutegirls.com/test.php Don't worry, it's just a blank page, with the form.

Comment: Ir you want in the bottom the position must be absolute. Otherwise, you make margin-top:100%

Comment: do you want `#login` to be at the bottom? Or will it have a height and you just want the `input`s to be at the bottom?

Comment: @AvAvt I like your answer the best, you should make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the margin from your form:

```
form {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in #LOGIN

```css
#login {
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
input {
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'login'>
<form method = 'POST' action = 'login.php'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'username' maxlength = '20' placeholder = 'username' size = '5'>
<input type = 'password' name = 'password' maxlength = '20' placeholder = 'password' size = '5'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Login'>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting bottom to 0 won't help very much if you don't set position to relative...

Anyway the problem you're facing has to do with the default CSS rules that the User Agent (the browser) is applying, that are setting a bottom margin to the form tag. Set it to 0 and you're done.

```
form {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to align it to the bottom of the container, position absolute would work better. But in this case, neither were assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The elements do not naturally inherit the position property of their parents.

This means your input elements don't have position absolute. Additionally, their parent doesn't have a height specified, so they can't really go to the bottom of the parent if they span the entire height of the parent.

What you probably want to do is assign #login a bottom value, and make sure its parent has a height assigned to it.

You need to make sure of three things.

1. The element has position:absolute;
2. The element has a bottom value.
3. The container (parent element) has a height assigned to it.